# TensorflowJS : What is the parameter filters?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm learning TensorflowJS and I'm working on CNN. 
I'm following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html#4) and in this tutorial you have to parameter the first layer like that

```
  // In the first layer of out convolutional neural network we have 
  // to specify the input shape. Then we specify some paramaters for 
  // the convolution operation that takes place in this layer.
  model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    inputShape: [IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS],
    kernelSize: 5,
    filters: 8,
    strides: 1,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'varianceScaling'
  }));

filters. The number of filter windows of size kernelSize to apply to the input data. Here, we will apply 8 filters to the data.
```

Despite the little explanation I still not understand what the filters are :( Can somebody explain me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct definition, but perhaps it will help you with intuition. Filters are like channels. If you have a 28 x 28 pix image and this image holds RGB colors, we can say you have 28 x 28 x 3 dimension size of a picture, where 3 = [red, green, blue]. If you set filters to 10, (and let's assume first two guys stay the same), you will get 28x28x10 dimensions for your original input. It's very useful for feature detection. But it's very expensive for computing.